# Processing 2 Sample Desktop/Wallpaper Color

Tags: arduino, processing

Wonder if anyone has any suggestions (including, "ya, not gonna happen");

I'm using Firmata on an Arduino and Processing is driving an RGB LED strip.  I'm wondering if as my desktop wallpaper changes that Processing can sample the color (RGB, HEX, Whatever) which would allow me to match the LED strip...

It seems far fetched to me but since I can read the line-in of the snd card and use it, I thought why not the color too.  Anyway thanks in advance.

Comment: What operating system?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Java mode, you can use the Robot class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

That class contains several functions that might be useful to you, including getPixelColor() which returns the color of the supplied position on the screen and createScreenCapture() that returns an image of the whole screen (or a subsection of it) that you can then use for averaging or sampling or whatever.